# Javascript > Show what Answered is

Tags: javascript

Ok, so I'm making a website for tutorials with JS and I'm working on a mini test on it. I'm wondering how I would go about adding a function that would tell the user on a popup window the correct answer and what they answered. I already have coded the correct answer, but I'm stuck with how I would create a function specifying in the popup box what they answered.

Here is the progress so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Tutorials - Review 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_alert()
{
alert("1. Correct Answer is: True" );
alert("2. Correct Answer is: True");
alert("3. Correct Answer is: True");
}
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<div id="logo">
<h1><a href="index.html">Javascript Tutorial</a></h1>
</div>
<div id="slogan">
<h2>Javascript Tutorial covering concepts</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li class="first current_page_item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="struct.html">Structured Programming</a></li>
<li><a href="sequence.html">Sequence Structure</a></li>
<li><a href="comparison.html">Pseudocode, JS and Flowcharts</a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="Workscited.html">Credits</a></li>
</ul>
<br class="clearfix" />
</div>
<div id="splash">
<img class="pic" src="http://i.imgur.com/pCvZ4.png" width="870" height="230" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="page">
<div id="content">
<div class="box">
<h2>Welcome to Javascript Tutorials 
<p>
This is <strong>Javascript</strong>,  quiz and test for the Three Control Structures.
<p>Comparing Pseudocode, JavaScript and Flowcharts</p>
<h3>Flowcharts can describe the same processes and information.</h3>
<form name="threecont">
<input type="radio" name="option1contr" value="1"/>True<br />
<input type="radio" name="option1contr" value="2" />False.<br />
<p>Psuedocode and flowcharts are both tools to help you develop the logic for an algorithm?</p>
<input type="radio" name="option2contr" value="4"/>True<br />
<input type="radio" name="option2contr" value="5" />False<br />
<p>IPO stands for Processing and output?</p>
<input type="radio" name="option2contr" value="7."/>True<br />
<input type="radio" name="option2contr" value="8" />False<br />
<input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
<div class="box" id="content-box1">
<ul class="section-list">
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<br class="clearfix" />
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
<div class="box">
<h3>Navigation</h3>
<ul class="list">
<li class="first"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="struct.html">Structured Programming</a></li>
<li><a href="sequence.html">Sequence Structure</a></li>
<li><a href="comparison.html">Pseudocode, JS and Flowcharts</a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="Workscited.html">Credits</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="box">
<h3>Javascript Test Review</h3>
<div class="date-list">
<ul class="list date-list">
<li class="first"><span class="date">2/21</span> <a href="review1.html">Review Structured Programming</a></li>
<li class="first"><span class="date">2/21</span> <a href="review2.html">Review Sequence Structure</a></li>
<li class="first"><span class="date">2/21</span> <a href="review3.html">Review Comparsion Quiz</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br class="clearfix" />
</div>
<div id="page-bottom">
<div id="page-bottom-content">
<h3>Javascript Tutorials</h3>
<p>
This website covers very basic Javascript chapters we've covered within class, the goal is to educate
computer users on our content that we have covered so far.
</p>
</div>
<div id="page-bottom-sidebar">
<h3>Links</h3>
<ul class="list">
<li class="first"><a href="struct.html">Structured Programming</a>
<li><a href="sequence.html">Sequence Structure</a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="comparison.html">Pseudocode, JS and Flowcharts</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<br class="clearfix" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright so I don't know if my anwser is the best way to go about it but here it goes anyways:

```
<p>Comparing Pseudocode, JavaScript and Flowcharts</p>
<h3>Flowcharts can describe the same processes and information.</h3>
<input type="radio" name="option1contr" value="1"/>True<br />
<input type="radio" name="option1contr" value="2" />False<br />
<p>Psuedocode and flowcharts are both tools to help you develop the logic for an algorithm?</p>
<input type="radio" name="option2contr" value="4"/>True<br />
<input type="radio" name="option2contr" value="5" />False<br />
<p>IPO stands for Processing and output?</p>
<input type="radio" name="option3contr" value="7"/>True<br />
<input type="radio" name="option3contr" value="8" />False<br />
<input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Submit" />
```

Well for starters, you might want to rename the radio's names(the ones after "IPO stands for Processing and output?") considering you would only be able to select one of the last 4. Also I got rid of the "." after the first False for consistency. (also got rid of the "." after 7 in the value of option3contr)

You could:

```
function show_alert(){
var thisArray =[document.threecont.option1contr, document.threecont.option2contr, document.threecont.option3contr];
var answer1 = find_User_Answers(thisArray[0]);
var answer2 = find_User_Answers(thisArray[1]);
var answer3 = find_User_Answers(thisArray[2]);

alert(answer1 + answer2 + answer3);

}

function find_User_Answers(someVariable){

var val = new Array();
var thisRadio = someVariable;

    for(var i = 0; i < thisRadio.length; i++ ){

    if(thisRadio[i].checked == true){

    if(thisRadio[i].value == "1" || thisRadio[i].value == "4" || thisRadio[i].value == "7"){
        val.push("true");
      }
        else{val.push("false");}
      }
     }//end radiogroup for loop

return val;
}
```

Right now it'll return the answers in a single line but they're in order ... It would now be a lot easier to figure out how to split them up such as

```
alert("You Answered: " + answer1);
```

I hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

Use a "modal dialog" not a pop-up. This is essentially an absolutely-positioned DIV that you populate with your content then show over the position of the click (or in the middle of the browser window).

- It starts of hidden
- You load content
- Position the element
- Show the element
- Hide it on click

Google "javascript modal dialog" there are lots of pre-made plugins that do this if you don't want to roll-your-own.

Comment: I don't want to use a modal dialog, I want to use an alert that will tell them.

Comment: You specifically say "how I would go about adding a function that would tell the user on a popup window" -- this is NOT an alert.